# Can you use MassTransit with IBM MQ?

Tags: .net, message-queue, ibm-mq, masstransit

If your architecture relays on IBM MQ as a messaging system, can you use MassTransit to publish messages or handle sagas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MassTransit does not include support for IBM MQ. Just Azure Service Bus or RabbitMQ. However, MassTransit is open source, and you are welcome to add the support yourself.